# SVA for verifying that two signals are equivalent after some delays

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have an SVA question :

Let's say we have signal wpo, and 19-21 clocks cycles later, we have wpo(the value at time 0) == out. How to write an SVA for that.
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
logic [103:0] temp; 
property check_property;
    @(posedge clk) disable iff (rst) 
    ##[19:21] (temp === wpo);
endproperty
check_property_A: assert property (check_property);
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  temp <= out;
end
```

So to recap wpo should have the value that out had 19-21 cycles earlier.

Comment: You need to provide a test case with a testbench to show your problem.

Comment: It is literally to verify the connectivity of pipes, that we're getting the right value to our module 19-21 cycles after)

Comment: Are you trying to say that `wpo` should have the value that `out` had 19-21 cycles earlier? Or the reverse. Please edit your question to clearly state which is the case.

Comment: @dave_59 Exactly that, wpo should have the value that out had 19-21 cycles earlier.

Comment: the code works as is, depending on the stimulus you provided. So, you should provide the stimulus you are interested in.  Also, you need to define what does not work and when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `temp` as a local variable of the property.

```
    property p(pi,po);
                 type(pi) temp;
                 (1,temp=pi) |-> ##[19:21] po == temp;
    endproperty
    assert property( @(posedge clk) p(out,wpo));
```